# SingleStore Spark Connector:NULLPointer Exception while Read/Write Operations

Tags: apache-spark, singlestore

Read/Write Operations are working from spark shell. But throwing NULLPointer Exception when executed from Development IDE locally.

```
   val df = spark.read
  .format("singlestore")
  .option("ddlEndpoint", "host:port")
  .option("user", "xxxxx")
  .option("password","xxxxx")
  .option("database","xxxxx")
  .load("schema.table_name")
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.singlestore.spark.JdbcHelpers$ConnectionHelpers.withStatement(JdbcHelpers.scala:26)
at com.singlestore.spark.JdbcHelpers$.getSinglestoreVersion(JdbcHelpers.scala:322)
at com.singlestore.spark.SQLGen$SQLGenContext$.getSinglestoreVersion(SQLGen.scala:532)
at com.singlestore.spark.SQLGen$SQLGenContext$.apply(SQLGen.scala:550)
at com.singlestore.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:332)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:242)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:230)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:197)
```

Below dependencies are set in the sbt.build file.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.7"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.7"
libraryDependencies += "com.singlestore" % "singlestore-spark-connector_2.11" % "3.1.2-spark-2.4.7"
libraryDependencies += "org.mariadb.jdbc" % "mariadb-java-client"  % "3.0.4"
```

Could someone please help me to resolve this . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to update one of your dependencies in the sbt.build file.

Try replacing:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mariadb.jdbc" % "mariadb-java-client"  % "3.0.4"
```

with

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mariadb.jdbc" % "mariadb-java-client"  % "2.+"
```